# Serializing classmethods in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, django-models, class-method, django-migrations

When I try to run `manage.py makemigrations` on Django 1.7, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <bound method ModelBase.get_default of <class 'printapp.models.JobConfiguration'>>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

So it looks like there's an issue with the method `get_default` that's defined on `JobConfiguration`, whose definition is repeated below:

```
@classmethod
def get_default(cls):
    result = cls()
    result.save()
    return result
```

Following the [link that was provided in the error message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing), it looks like serializing "class references" is a supported feature.

**Is a "class reference" the same as a `@classmethod`?**

**How would I put a "class reference" in the "module's top-level scope"?**

**Why do methods have to be tracked by migrations?** I was under the assumption that migrations are for database schemas, which only track the type of data stored, not the type of methods used by a class.

It's interesting to note: changing the definition of `get_default` to a static method as repeated below solves the problem, but at the cost of having to hard-code the `JobConfiguration` classname.

```
@staticmethod
def get_default():
    result = JobConfiguration()
    result.save()
    return result
```

(Some context: this method is being referenced as `JobConfiguration.get_default` from within a `models.OneToOneField(JobConfiguration, default=JobConfiguration.get_default)` with the effect of creating a new JobConfiguration for each one of these fields created.)

Comment: Just out of interest, what does this give you over `JobConfiguration.objects.create()`? It's still one command, barely more typing.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that method was available. I'll probably change it in my code, but I'm still interested in knowing why the code is failing as is.

Answer (score 0):

> Migrations are just Python files containing the old definitions of
>   your models - thus, to write them, Django must take the current state
>   of your models and serialize them out into a file.

classmethod is bind to the class. Since the decorator wraps the method, the serializer faces an ambiguity what to bind: the wrapper or the methos, and it fails. With static method there is no such issue because it's a simple function attached to the class.